# Linux: Access Files In Another Partition

Tags: linux, partition-recovery

I had a LG N1T1 NAS drive that got shut down during a power outage. When power returned, the permissions were gone. I couldn't access the web services and the shared folders wouldn't open. I took the hard drive out of it, connected it to a computer and booted it up with a new install of Linux.

I don't have much experience with Linux and need a bit of help accessing the files on one of the partitions.

** Linux Partition Image **

Here is a picture of the Partition I'm trying to get into. I've tried /dev/sda3 and it says: Permission Denied, I've also tried:

```
chmod 777 /dev/sda3
```

which returned:

> Operation Not Permitted

I tried this as well:

```
chown username /dev/sda3
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Update:
I installed the mdadm package from the internet directly and got that to work. But when mounting I get this:
Error mounting /dev/md0 at /media/casestaffingadmin/25212cd2-5044-4814-8f3b-598cb41ceaeb: Command-line `mount -t "ext3" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/md0" "/media/casestaffingadmin/25212cd2-5044-4814-8f3b-598cb41ceaeb"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the partition or drive first to do that, you need to enter this command

`sudo mount <partition-name> <mount-point>`

in your case `partition-name` is `/dev/sda3` and `mount-point` is generally `/mnt`.

and the you can `cd` into `/mnt` and access or modify files

**EDIT:**

If your partition if you get `mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'` you need to `mdadm --assemble --run --force /dev/md0 /dev/sda3`  first and then can mount partition

Comment: Hey DenisKa, 

Thank you for your reply! I tried running that command but I get the error: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'

Any thoughts? I looked at some other threads that said to use mdadm but for that I getK mdadm package has no installation candidate

Comment: what linux distro you are using? and if ubuntu did you try `sudo apt update` first ?

Comment: 4.8.0 - 36 Generic
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: I tried 'sudo apt update' and got the same result when I tried to run 'sudo apt install mdadm' and 'mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sda3'

Comment: can you show me output of `mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sda3`?

Comment: Here it is, I had previously tried to install it and got the same result.

http://imgur.com/a/Mjehq

Comment: It is strange mdadm is already in Ubuntu's repositories. Has anyone edited your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file? And print the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is a fresh install from a boot drive. Do you know of another command that has similar functionality to mdadm?

Comment: `testdisk` can help